# ant-contrib foreach: how to identify the correct parallel target in the log

Tags: ant, sonarqube, ant-contrib

I'm using Ant-contrib foreach task to run SonarQube analysis, with parallel target calls.

The problem is that the log is being displayed as part of the [foreach] which makes it hard to read since there are concurrent execution being logged.

```
  [foreach] 01:18:12.054 INFO  - Initializing Hibernate
  [foreach] 01:18:12.065 INFO  - Initializing Hibernate
  [foreach] 01:18:12.098 INFO  - Initializing Hibernate
  [foreach] 01:18:16.504 ERROR - Server ID is invalid. Please check settings.
  [foreach] 01:18:16.517 ERROR - Server ID is invalid. Please check settings.
  [foreach] 01:18:16.530 ERROR - Server ID is invalid. Please check settings.
  [foreach] 01:18:16.533 ERROR - Server ID is invalid. Please check settings.
  [foreach] 01:18:17.360 INFO  - Load project repositories
  [foreach] 01:18:17.363 INFO  - Load project repositories
```

In the example above, the repeated lines refers to different executions (each execution for a specific project).

Is there a way to identify each execution within foreach loop (e.g., [foreach:project1], [foreach:project2])?

Otherwise, what other strategy could be used to improve this?

I was wondering if it's possible to implement a Log Decorator that adds a prefix in each log when executing, based on a variable within the loop.

Comment: What Ant task generates the log messages such as `Initializing Hibernate`? Please post the Ant script of `<foreach>` and the target of `<foreach>` as well.

Comment: @ChadNouis this log is just an example. the ant script is calling Sonar Ant task, that log is generated by that task: <sonar:sonar xmlns:sonar="antlib:org.sonar.ant"/>

Answer (score 0):

Every Ant task supports the `taskname` attribute. The value of `taskname` determines the "banner" used when a task logs a message:

### build.xml

```
<project name="ant-taskname" default="run">
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml" />
    <target name="my-echo">
        <echo taskname="echo-${letter}">Letter ${letter}.</echo>
    </target>
    <target name="run">
        <foreach list="a,b,c" target="my-echo" param="letter" parallel="true"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

### Output

```
run:

my-echo:

my-echo:

my-echo:
   [echo-b] Letter b.
   [echo-a] Letter a.
   [echo-c] Letter c.
```

The output shows banners such as `[echo-b]` even though the `<echo>` task actually logged the message. You can adapt this solution for the Sonar task.

Comment: Your answer already helped me to proceed further, but I don't have a solution yet. It seems <sonar:sonar> task is producing a log (maybe from a java call) that is caught by the foreach thread, because the foreach task is using a different thread. If I reduce the thread count to 1 the [foreach] text is not even logged. So the question here is: is there a way to decorate   or redirect the log so it can be identified which thread/foreach is producing that log?

Comment: Moreover, if I try to name the foreach task using <foreach taskname="" ...> I can see that the parallel foreach entries share the same name, which is random, I assume it uses the name of the first foreach thread that starts executing